# Xcode crashes when recording a UI test on a physical device

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having trouble with the following UI test phenomenon.

1. Open a UI test code XxxUITests.swift.
2. Create test function like

```
func testX(){
}
```

and set cursor in the function.

3. Start run application on iOS 17.2 physical device.
4. Click [Record UI Test] on Xcode.

Then Xcode terminates abnormally.
If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.
Thanks.

macOS : Sonoma 14.2
Xcode : 15.1
Test device iOS : 17.2

I searched the internet but could not find a solution